# How to find the password to my iPad's currently-connected Wi-Fi network?

Tags: ios, ipad, network, wifi

I am connected to my wifi on my iPad but I want to know if there is a way to find the password that is put in to get connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using iCloud Keychain, the password is synced to your keychain on your Mac and is therefore accessible in Keychain Access.

Open Keychain Access, select the keychain and look for the Wi-Fi network. Clicking show password will prompt for your password, then the network password will be displayed.